# why /tmp has permission to read/write only own file/dir in lunux

Tags: linux

I came across the interview and asked about /tmp folder.
any one can create file under this folder but cant delete file of others even though having 777 permission to file.why?

Comment: Are you asking why (i.e. how) `/tmp` works this way, or are you asking why it should work that way (i.e. why is this a good thing)? Your question as stated is a bit ambiguous...

Answer (score 1):

That is due to the [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit).

The */tmp* directory has mode 1777 to cause precisely this behavior.